# Compile Error in vandersnatch_vrfs crate in SDK version 1.3.0

Tags: versioning, compile, releases, vandersnatch-vrfs

I'm trying to update my node from SDK version 1.2.0 to 1.3.0. To do so I make this change to each package in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
- sp-core = { tag = "polkadot-v1.2.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk" }
+ sp-core = { tag = "polkadot-v1.3.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk" }
```

Here is the [full commit](https://github.com/Off-Narrative-Labs/Tuxedo/commit/715adccffa29d04146f70e8c62e79da723e6a5fd)

For some reason a crate somewhere in the dependency graph called `vandersnatch_vrfs` is not compiling. Any idea what I might need to do?

```
error[E0616]: field `keyset_part_size` of struct `ring::PiopParams` is private
  --> /home/joshy/.cargo/git/checkouts/ring-vrf-fa8519651343a7ee/4b09416/bandersnatch_vrfs/src/ring.rs:70:26
   |
70 |         self.piop_params.keyset_part_size
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ private field

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0616`.
error: could not compile `bandersnatch_vrfs` (lib) due to previous error
```

Comment: DQ: Have you tried to set it to `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.3.0"`?

Comment: @ArturGontijo `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.3.0"` fixes it. Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it? I've updated my question to explicitly state what I had tried. In your answer, please include the semantics of the release branches vs tags if you know it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I changed to `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.3.0"` on my own code base but I'm still getting the exact same compilation error.

Comment: @KazunobuNdong that's odd =/. Maybe you should run a `cargo clean` and rebuild everything from the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set it to `branch = "release-polkadot-v1.3.0"`?

I can see that the `tag = "polkadot-v1.3.0"` is not pointing to the same commit as that branch is, so maybe we need to update that tag. Not sure who would be able to do that but I'll communicate that in the Element's channel.

(I recommended that branch as I'm using it on some projects and it is working fine)

Comment: Indeed, switching to that branch and running `cargo update` worked for me. Thank you.  Regarding updating the tag, I think git tags are supposed to never change once published. [git tag docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).